# I have problems with Realtek rtl8723be on my HP, hq tre laptop. Need to restore to default values?

Tags: 16.04, hp, rtl8723be

I got this trouble with WIFI connection. At the beginning just turn off when my laptop was on for 2 or 3 hours, and i needed to reboot.

But, i tried to fix it and just become worst. I follow this steps:  https://www.taringa.net/+linux/realtek-8723be-wifi-ubuntu-solucionado_v6xou and my WIFI turn off. Don't work anymore.

I tried other solutions of the HP official page, but nothing works. Please,if there exists s**ome way to return to got** 2 or 3 hours of **connection**, just let me know. I really need (or can) return to default values for WIFI?

**What information you need to help me?** Also let me know.

*I adjunt my wifi-info-script*

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4MGsPCzpJd/

*The response to `sudo modprobe rtl8723`*

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723be': Required key not available

*The response to 'sudo updatedb && locate rtlwifi_new'*

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TFW8WRwk6Q/

***Thanks :D***

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact response to the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe rtl8723be` and also: sudo updatedb && locate rtlwifi_new` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: All right! Also, my laptop not shows any networks.

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules You probably should disable secure boot.

Comment: Thanks so much. It was the secure boot, now works perfectly.